# com.htc.bg 'process stopped unexpectedly' on HTC Desire when Facebook sync active

Tags: contacts, htc-desire

Once per hour, I get a message on my HTC Desire saying that a process has stopped unexpectedly. It is the com.htc.bg process. The problem disappears if I disable the syncing of my Facebook account to the phone. To back this up, I have found that the list of contacts downloaded from Facebook is incomplete, so I am wondering if it is crashing halfway through the sync process.

Rather than just disabling it to stop the error, I want the Facebook contact sync to work properly. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Please change the title of your question to indicate that your problem is with Facebook contact sync. "Process stopped unexpectedly" is very generic and could apply to anything. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem with the contacts sync for an Exchange account.  I found that deleting the account on my Desire and re-adding it made the errors go away.  Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this in another forum](http://androidforums.com/htc-droid-eris/59163-process-com-htc-bg-has-stopped-unexpectedly-please-try-again-wtf.html):

1. Go to the *People* (contact list) app
2. Go to the Online Directories (Globe) tab
3. Select Facebook
4. You will be asked to log in to your Facebook account. Once logged in, you will see all of your contacts on your Facebook account.
5. Return to the full list of your contacts on the phone and try and sync